# New-AzureQuickVM not creating VM on exsisting Cloud Service?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to run the following Azure Powershell cmdlet to provision a new Virtual Machine on a existing Cloud Service.

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureService | ft ServiceName

ServiceName                                                                                                                                                                    
-----------                                                                                                                                                                    
$AZURETEST-EUWEST0                                                                                                                                                                 
$AZURETEST-JPWEST0                                                                                                                                                                 
$AZURETEST-USEAST0                                                                                                                                                                 
$AZURETEST-USWEST0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

PS C:\> $image = "a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-201505.01-en.us-127GB.vhd"

PS C:\> New-AzureQuickVM -Windows -ServiceName "$AZURETEST-USEAST0" -name "AZURESVM-USE1" -ImageName $image -Password Password1 -AdminUsername admin -WaitForBoot
New-AzureQuickVM : ResourceNotFound: The deployment name '$AZURETEST-USEAST0' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureQuickVM -Windows -ServiceName "$AZURETEST-USEAST0" -name "AZURESVM-USE1" -Im ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureQuickVM], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.PersistentVMs.NewQuickVM

New-AzureQuickVM : Sequence contains no matching element
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureQuickVM -Windows -ServiceName "$AZURETEST-USEAST0" -name "AZURESVM-USE1" -Im ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureQuickVM], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.PersistentVMs.NewQuickVM


PS C:\>
```

What doesn't make sense is I'm getting an error that says my Cloud Service - or Deployment Name doesn't exist when you can clearly see it returned when I listed all the available Cloud Services!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, admin as administrator account name will not work. It's a reserved word, once you get past the service name, it will break on this one.

Second, there's nothing wrong with your powershell command and I tested exactly with the same parameters to make sure. I can bet it's the "$" you used for the cloud service name that is being misinterpreted by the cmdlet.

Since you can't rename cloud services, create a new one without the "$" and try again to see if it works.

**Update:** This is what happens when i try to create CS from the portal with the "$" as first character:

> "This field can contain only letters, numbers, and hyphens. The first
>   and last character in the field must be a letter or number.
>   Trademarks, reserved words, and offensive words are not allowed."

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified I merely changed the name of my cloud service and didn't use my standard name to avoid prying eyes on the internet.

If you just go by my example, try to use the New-AzureQuickVM cmdlet to create a VM in an existing Cloud Service you'll get said error.

Comment: I copy pasted your powershell script. No errors. My VM deployed successfully. The parameters are correct and I made sure to create the CS prior running this cmd. The only possible case would be that your cloud service name is really not matching.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter all parameters inline without using named parameters (e.g $image). that solved it for me. 
Here is a working example:

```
$image = "a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-Datacenter-20160229-en.us-127GB.vhd"
$location = 'West Europe'

 New-AzureQuickVM -Windows -Location $location -ServiceName "RamiSOTest1-cs" -name "RamiSOTest1-VM" -ImageName $image -Password 'RamiPass-1' -AdminUsername 'rami' -WaitForBoot
```